# Add new column via liquibase only if not already exists

Tags: liquibase

I want to use liquibase on spring boot startup to add a new column to an existing table.

But in the particular schema I'm working with I have already added it manually.

So I get an error on startup indicating the column already exists (because it does):

```
Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource 
[...LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: LiquibaseException: 
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for 
change set db/changelog/AlterTable_MyTable_AddNewCol.xml::1::me (manual):
 Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
Duplicate column name 'new_col' [Failed SQL: (1060) 
ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table ADD new_col INT NULL]
```

Is there a liquibase precondition option to add the column only if it *does not already exist*; and if it already exists, don't error out?

I tried the following and the process errors out with the above error:

```
<databaseChangeLog ... >
    <changeSet author="me (manual)" id="1">
        <preConditions onFail="WARN">
            <columnExists tableName="my_table" columnName="new_col" />
        </preConditions>
        <addColumn tableName="my_table">
            <column name="new_col" type="integer"/>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<not>` tag around `columnsExists` in your code, like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog ... >
    <changeSet author="me (manual)" id="1">
        <preConditions onFail="WARN">
          <not>
            <columnExists tableName="my_table" columnName="new_col" />
          <not>
        </preConditions>
        <addColumn tableName="my_table">
            <column name="new_col" type="integer"/>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```